# AngularJS - Getting a website content (GET) from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm trying to do a quite simple task - getting the html content of a website with `AngularJS`. This is my code:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: "http://www.google.com",
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
            }})
            .success(function(d){ console.log( "yay" ); })
            .error(function(d){ console.log( "nope" ); });
```

The problem is that I get the `CORS` error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I familiar with the `CORS` issue quite well, I know it's a server issue mainly. But still, can anyone suggest (if possible) a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to make cross origin request to google.com. Google needs to accept your domain in order to do CORS. You do not have permission to do that action. 
Please look this [documentation about CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

The solution is to make a request to your backend service and let that service fetch the content and return it back to client side.

Comment: Not sure your completely right. I know the server need to enable it, but how does this chrome extension does it - https://github.com/jeremys/Simple-Rest-Client-Chrome-Extension? From looking at the code it seems like he does xhr request, and by monitoring the network, there is no server call.

Comment: That is for [package app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). It is possible but not for hosted app.